# How to persist users in Grafana open source (docker swarm)

Tags: docker, grafana, persistence, rbac, multiple-users

I have deployed grafana could persist dashboard,datasource and LDAP but I'm **not able to persist users** to acheive dashboard level access.
Whenever the **stack gets redeployed the users data will be erased** but I'm amazed when the service gets erased the users will still be able to login
I have mounted a volume as well!
Using grafana 9.0 open source (deployed it as a stack in docker swarm).
I want to persist users is there a way to do it via configuration file?